# Copy cell value to another cell on double-click

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I need VBA code in Excel. If I double-click a cell in E-or-F-or-G column, the displaying value should be copied in corresponding H cell.  Please advise, I am new user.

```
       E       F       G      H
1   1.00    0.50    0.00     
2   1.00    0.50    0.00     
3   1.00    0.50    0.00
```

Comment: I do not want to use formula, the user will double click E-or-F-G cell and double click it.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Not tested:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

if Target.Column>=5 and Target.Column<=7 then
 Cells(Target.Row,8)=Target.Value
endif

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sigil, I will try, but I want you to know that there are 33 rows, will it be effective for all rows?